# Which minimum android version is required for speech to text application

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I have done the coding for converting speech into text.I just want to know which minimum version of android required for this.

Comment: Are you asking about Text To Speech or Speech To Text?

Answer (score 2):

[Text to Speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) was introduced in **Android 1.6 : Donut**, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-1.6-highlights.html).

Also check out the blogpost [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html).

**EDIT :** In case, you meant [RecognizerIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html) of the **SpeechToText** API, it requires an API level of **Android 1.5 : Cupcake**.

Answer (score 1):

The package [android.speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html) has existed since API level 3 (i.e. Android v1.5). Many classes, interfaces, constants in this package have appeared much later. The `RecognitionService`-class (which many keyboard apps use) came in API level 8. Not much has happened since but every API level has still added a few things.

So it really depends on which interface your app wants to use (the plain `RecognizerIntent`-intent or the `RecognizerService`), and which speech recognizer implementation it wants to use (Google Voice Search?) and for which versions this implementation is available.